# C#, Cannot find an UrlEncoder that works with oAuth and the facebook server-side login process

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, urlencode

I'm trying to make a server-side login process with facebook in my C# MVC application.

At the moment of submiting an status update in my app it has to publish it on facebook, I make a redirect to:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={0}&scope={1}&redirect_uri={2}
```

Using this Method:

```
Response.Redirect(...);
```

where my redirect uri is encoded like this:

```
HttpUtility.UrlEnconde("http://local.mydomain.com/getAuthToken?message=the original message");
```

And back into my MVC app (after accepting the fb permissions) the getAuthToken action makes a request to the URI:

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&code={2}&redirect_uri={3}
```

Using this Method:

```
 using (var wc = new WebClient()){
      wc.DownloadString(...)
 }
```

where my redirect uri again is encoded like this:

```
 HttpUtility.UrlEnconde("http://local.mydomain.com/getAuthToken?message=the original message");
```

**if "*the original message*" contains no spaces it works but when I start adding spaces and other special characters I get an OAuth Exception:**

*Error validating verification code*

So my question is, **what kind of URL Enconding should I have to use to make it work**

I Found something [here](http://blog.stephendenton.com/code/a-proper-urlencode-function-for-oauth-in-c-sharp/) but I'm getting the same error, I dont know if I need a special method to make the redirects or if I need diferent Encodings for this two request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this I used this to encode:

```
static public string EncodeTo64(string toEncode)
  {
     byte[] toEncodeAsBytes
           = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(toEncode);
     string returnValue
           = Convert.ToBase64String(toEncodeAsBytes);
     return returnValue;
  }
```

and this to decode

```
  static public string DecodeFrom64(string encodedData)
  {
     byte[] encodedDataAsBytes
         = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedData);
     string returnValue =
        Encoding.ASCII.GetString(encodedDataAsBytes);
     return returnValue;
  }
```

In case someone needs it
Thaks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look at Dino Cheisa's excellent OAuth.Manager class.  This does the URL Encoding properly.  You can get it from http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/OAuthManager1.1/html/N_OAuth.htm